# TYPO3 object storage table does not exist - (tx_extbase_persistence_objectstorage)

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I recently upgraded a relatively old System TYPO3 4.7 => 6.2.
I changed alot of namespaces/imports etc. and fixed stuff here and there. After the system was stable I made some changes in the extension builder and added some new fields.
I had to change some code in some files that threw errors but after that I was able to successfully save in the extension builder.

It added the correct classes,attributes and actions but now the system shows me this error:
1247602160: Table 'keepins_upgrade.tx_extbase_persistence_objectstorage' doesn't exist

Usually this error is related to models that are mapped incorrectly in the typoscript file but this seems different.. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Shot from the hip: you have one or more properties in your domain model which is annotated incorrectly - so it is read as a 1:1 relation to ObjectStorage, not a 1:n to a collection of another object. Or, less likely given your previous version, you've annotated a setter method or controller action so it requires an instance of ObjectStorage, but neglected to add PHPDOC that defines the true expected child type or is somehow else invalid or not connected to the right property.